# Macro Slicer runtime error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros, tabla-dinámica

Necesito crear un slicer que afecte todas las tablas pivote que pertenezcan a cierto tipo de ordenes de trabajo. Para eso primero creo el slicer a partir de una tabla pivote, y luego trato de agregarle las demas pivotes por medio de una macro

```
Sub Button13_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivots")

    'CE OP Slicers
    'Mgr Slicer
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable3"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable4"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable5"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable7"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable27"))

    'Range Slicer
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable2"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable3"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable4"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable5"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable7"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges1").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable27"))

'SLED Pivot Tables
'Mgr Slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable8"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable9"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable10"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable11"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable12"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable14"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable30"))

    'Range Slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable8"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable9"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable10"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable11"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable12"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable14"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges3").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable30"))

'CA Pivot tables
    'Mgr slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable15"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable16"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable17"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable18"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable19"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable21"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable31"))

    'Range Slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable15"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable16"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable17"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable18"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable19"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable21"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable31"))

'CE Future POs
    'Mgr slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable22"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable23"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable24"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable25"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable28"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable29"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable32"))

    'Range slicers
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable22"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable23"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable24"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable25"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable28"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable29"))

    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Ranges2").PivotTables. _
    AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable32"))
End Sub
```

Cuando lo inspecciono en la ventana de macros no me arroja ningun tipo de error, pero cuando lo corro me arroja el siguiente mensaje

> runtime error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error

Y cuando abro el debug siempre me apunta a la siguiente linea de código

```
'CE OP Slicers
'Mgr Slicer
ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables. _
AddPivotTable (sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque podria estarme dando ese error?  Las tablas pivote no tienen ningun problema, ya que antes de este paso hago otro donde les cambio el datasource tambien via módulo.

Gracias por su tiempo.

**Edit:** añado pantallazo con referencias activas en el proyecto

[image: Referencias activas]

Comment: ¿Qué referencia tienes activada para que te reconozca el objeto `SlicerCaches`?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes uso el Thisworkbook con el dato que aparece en el campo "Name to use in formulas" o a que referencia te refieres? soy nuevo en esto de vba asi que no me quedó muy claro

Comment: Las referencias te dan acceso a bibliotecas de Objetos Adicionales que, por defecto, no reconoce VBA. En mi VBA probé tu código porque no reconoce ese objeto, y entonces eso explicaría el error que tienes. ¿Desarrollaste tú el código o lo copiaste? En el editor de VBA, en Herramientas-> Referencias, mira todas las que tengas activadas

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes añado screenshot con las referencias activas en el proyecto. ¿Hay alguna referencia especificia que deba buscar y seleccionar?

Comment: Pues tiene toda la pinta. Que yo sepa, el objeto que tú estás usando, `SlicerCaches`,no viene en las referencias por defecto (que son las que tú tienes activadas, aunque tus librerías son 16.0 y las mías son 12.0. Esto es porque yo tengo Excel 2007 y tú posiblemente una versión más avanzada). El problema es que, yo por lo menos, desconozco qué referencia específica necesitas :(. ¿De dónde sacaste el código? ¿No lo menciona en la fuente?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes de esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713537/excel-vba-create-a-macro-to-connect-a-slicer-to-multiple-pivot-tables

Comment: Los slicers son objetos de Tablas Dinámicas pero solamente en versiones de Excel 2010 en adelante. Yo tengo 2007 y lamento no poder ayudar más. Mi referencia se limita a la librería 12.0 y por ello, no tengo este objeto ni conozco su sintaxis ni demás. Tendrás que mirar en SO.COM a ver que te dicen

Comment: Aun así, viendo la sintaxis, ¿no sobra una pareja de paréntesis? ¿No debería ser `ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Mgr1").PivotTables.AddPivotTable sh.PivotTables("PivotTable1")` ? . De hecho, es lo que mencionan justo en el enlace que me has pasado